# ¿Como obtengo un objeto que esta dentro de otro con nodejs y mongodb?

Tags: nodejs, mongodb

Necesito obtener la información contenida el array denominado `detalleInsumos` mediante el `_id` de ese objeto.

He intentado de muchas maneras, pero aun no he dado con la solución a mi problema, ya que siempre me muestra todos los objetos de ese documento, lo cual no me sirve.

Este es el documento del cual necesito sacar esa información

```
{
    "_id":{"$oid":"5f9041196462be3c5ca1e53d"},
    "codigoFinca":"000",
    "nombreFinca":"PROVINCIANA",
    "fechaRegistro":"2020-10-21",
    "semanaRegistro":"43",
    "usuarioRegistro":"cotorreo",
    "trabajadoresFinca":[
        {
            "porcentajeRecargo":0,
            "_id":{"$oid":"5f9041196462be3c5ca1e53e"},
            "udpTrabajador":[
                {
                    "unidadesAPagar":null,
                    "valorUnidad":"",
                    "areaLaborada":"2",
                    "semanaNormal":null,
                    "semanaAtrazos":null,
                    "_id":{"$oid":"5f9041196462be3c5ca1e53f"},
                    "detalleInsumos":[
                        {"_id":{"$oid":"5f9041196462be3c5ca1e540"},
                         "codigoInsumo":"20000001",
                         "descripcionInsumo":"NYLON X 5 KILOS",
                         "cantidadAplicada":"153",
                         "idRDI":"426715",
                         "idDetalleSaldo":"24070"
                        }
                    ],
                    "codigoLabor":"101",
                    "nombreLabor":"AMARRE",
                    "loteLaboro":"1"
                }
            ],
            "codigoTrabajador":"0000",
            "nombresTrabajador":"HUMBERTO  MENA MOSQUERA",
            "horasJornada":"10",
            "horasLaboradas":"10"
        }
    ],
    "createdAt":{"$date":"2020-10-21T14:09:29.876Z"},
    "updatedAt":{"$date":"2020-10-21T15:09:51.657Z"},
    "__v":0
}
```

Y esto es lo que he intentado desde nodejs.

```
const consultauno = await Modelo.findOne({
                'trabajadoresFinca.udpTrabajador.detalleInsumos._id': new ObjectId(idInsumo)
            },
            {
                "trabajadoresFinca.udpTrabajador.detalleInsumos": 1
            });
            console.log(consultauno);
```

Comment: Imagino estás usando mongoose, cuál es la salida que te da?

Comment: Hola, me trae todo el objeto como respuesta, en este caso es el mismo que coloque de ejemplo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**PROBLEMA**

Se desea obtener un elemento de una lista que pertenece a un subdocumento de un documento en una colección de MongoDB.

Se realiza la consulta a la base de datos utilizando el método [`findOne()`](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.findOne) de un [Modelo](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/models.html) de [Mongoose](https://mongoosejs.com).

La consulta se realiza utilizando el siguiente filtro y proyección:

```js
//filtro:
{ 'trabajadoresFinca.udpTrabajador.detalleInsumos._id': new ObjectId(idInsumo) }

//proyección:
{ 'trabajadoresFinca.udpTrabajador.detalleInsumos': 1 }
```

Sin embargo el resultado trae toda la lista de elementos de `detalleInsumos`.

**SOLUCIÓN**

La solución está en comprender un poco cómo funciona el método `findOne()` (aplica también para los métodos [`find()`](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.find) y [`findById()`](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.findById)).

El resultado actual es el esperado para la consulta realizada con el método `findOne()`, ya que la proyección sólo te devolverá el campo `_id` del documento al que pertenece la lista y te devolverá el campo `detalleInsumos` con todos sus elementos, ya que eso es lo que especificas en la proyección.

Los método `findOne()`, `find()`, y `findById()` no realizan un proceso de filtrado de los componentes de un documento a menos que utilices el [operador posicional de proyección (`$`)](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/projection/positional/#proj._S_). Sin embargo el mismo no funciona en un `Array` anidado, tal como lo tienes en tu documento. Por lo tanto la solución está en filtrar el resultado una vez obtenido o en realizar un complejo proceso de agregación para obtener el resultado ya filtrado.

**Filtrando el resultado actual**

Una vez obtenido el resultado, usando la consulta que tienes actualmente, el mismo podría verse parecido a lo siguiente:

```js
{
  "_id": "5f9041196462be3c5ca1e53d",
  "trabajadoresFinca": [
    {
      "udpTrabajador": [
        {
          "detalleInsumos": [
            {
              "_id": "5f9041196462be3c5ca1e540",
              "codigoInsumo": "20000001"
            },
            {
              "_id": "5f9041196462be3c5ca1e541",
              "codigoInsumo": "20000002"
            },
            {
              "_id": "5f9041196462be3c5ca1e542",
              "codigoInsumo": "20000003"
            },
            {
              "_id": "5f9041196462be3c5ca1e543",
              "codigoInsumo": "20000004"
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Usando el método [`filter()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Array/filter) del tipo `Array` de Javascript.

Por ejemplo:

```js
let idInsumo = "5f9041196462be3c5ca1e540";

let result = {
  _id: "5f9041196462be3c5ca1e53d",
  trabajadoresFinca: [
    {
      udpTrabajador: [
        {
          detalleInsumos: [
            {
              _id: "5f9041196462be3c5ca1e540",
              codigoInsumo: "20000001"
            },
            {
              _id: "5f9041196462be3c5ca1e541",
              codigoInsumo: "20000002"
            },
            {
              _id: "5f9041196462be3c5ca1e542",
              codigoInsumo: "20000003"
            },
            {
              _id: "5f9041196462be3c5ca1e543",
              codigoInsumo: "20000004"
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}

// filtramos
let filteredInsumos = result.trabajadoresFinca[0].udpTrabajador[0].detalleInsumos.filter(detalle => detalle._id === idInsumo);

// mostramos
console.log(filteredInsumos);

// muestra:
// [
//   {
//     "_id": "5f9041196462be3c5ca1e540",
//     "codigoInsumo": "20000001"
//   }
// ]
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {
  min-height: 100%;
  top: 0;
}
```

Con esto, el `Array` llamado `filteredInsumos` tiene todos los elementos que correspondan con el valor `idInsumo`. Notemos que hemos usado el indicador posicional establecido a 0 (cero) para cada `Array` superior. Esto es porque estamos buscando en el primer elemento de cada uno de los `Array`. En tu pregunta, no aclaras si el `Array` llamado `trabajadoresFinca` o el llamado `udpTrabajador` tienen más de un elemento. Además, no estoy tomando en cuenta el caso en que la consulta no devuelva resultado, situación que claramente debemos considerar.

**Usando un proceso de agregación**

Podemos filtrar los datos directamente desde la Base de Datos, usando un [proceso de agregación](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/aggregation/). El cual consiste en realizar una serie de etapas en las cuales vamos dando forma a los datos que necesitamos.

La primera etapa será una etapa [`$match`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/match/index.html) para filtrar todos aquellos documentos que coincidan con el parámetro de búsqueda.

```js
const aggregate = [
  {
    $match: {
      'trabajadoresFinca.udpTrabajador.detalleInsumos._id': ObjectId(idInsumo)
    }
  }
]
```

Notemos que para poder usar el campo `_id` como filtro, el valor de `idInsumo` debe ser convertido previamente a un tipo `ObjectId`. Para ello vamos a requerir el tipo `ObjectId` de Mongoose:

```js
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const { ObjectId } = mongoose.Types;
```

Ahora, para filtrar los documentos que nos interesan, podemos usar una etapa de filtrado, pero primero debemos desenvolver (separar) los elementos contenidos en los campos de tipo `Array` llamados `trabajadoresFinca` y `udpTrabajador`. Para ello usaremos una etapa [`$unwind`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/index.html) para cada `Array`:

```js
const aggregate = [
  {
    $match: {
      'trabajadoresFinca.udpTrabajador.detalleInsumos._id': ObjectId(idInsumo)
    }
  },
  {
    $unwind: 'trabajadoresFinca'
  },
  {
    $unwind: 'trabajadoresFinca.udpTrabajadores'
  }
]
```

Ahora que hemos convertido cada `Array` en un documento anidado, podemos aplicar el filtro sobre el `Array` de `detalleInsumos`, para ello usaremos el operador [`$filter`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/filter/index.html) en combinación con el operador [`$project`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/project/index.html):

```js
const aggregate = [
  {
    $match: {
      'trabajadoresFinca.udpTrabajador.detalleInsumos._id': ObjectId(idInsumo)
    }
  },
  {
    $unwind: 'trabajadoresFinca'
  },
  {
    $unwind: 'trabajadoresFinca.udpTrabajadores'
  },
  {
    $project: {
      detalleInsumos: {
        $filter: {
          input: '$trabajadoresFinca.udpTrabajador.detalleInsumos',
          as: 'detalle',
          cond: {
            $eq: [
              '$$detalle._id',
              ObjectId(idInsumo)
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
]
```

En esta última etapa estamos proyectando un campo que llamaremos `detalleInsumos`, el cual contiene todos los elementos que pasan el filtro aplicado en el operador `$filter`.

Debemos destacar que hay que tomar en cuenta la conversión de tipos, ya que Mongoose no lo hará por nosotros cuando se trata de un proceso de agregación. Si no tomamos en cuenta este detalle, podemos estar comparando un valor de tipo `ObjectId` (el campo `_id` en un documento de MongoDB es de tipo `ObjectId`) con un valor de tipo `String`, lo cual siempre devolverá `false`.

Un ejemplo de la implementación anterior puede verse en el siguiente [Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/lCoSJXaPidy).

Nuevamente, habrá que tomar en cuenta el caso en que tanto el `Array` de `trabajadoresFinca` y `udpTrabajador` tengan más de un elemento, lo cual puede provocar resultados no esperados. Mi respuesta se basa en el documento mostrado en la pregunta.

Para usar la agregación antes mostrada en Mongoose, podrías tener un código parecido al siguiente, usando el método [`aggregate()`](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api/aggregate.html#aggregate_Aggregate) del modelo:

```js
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const { ObjectId } = mongoose.Types;
const idInsumo = '5f9041196462be3c5ca1e540'; // <- es un String

const agregacion = [
  {
    $match: {
      'trabajadoresFinca.udpTrabajador.detalleInsumos._id': ObjectId(idInsumo)
    }
  },
  {
    $unwind: 'trabajadoresFinca'
  },
  {
    $unwind: 'trabajadoresFinca.udpTrabajadores'
  },
  {
    $project: {
      detalleInsumos: {
        $filter: {
          input: '$trabajadoresFinca.udpTrabajador.detalleInsumos',
          as: 'detalle',
          cond: {
            $eq: [
              '$$detalle._id',
              ObjectId(idInsumo)
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
];

// cuando trabajamos con Promesas y await debemos usar try / catch
try {
  const resultado = await Model.aggregate(agregacion).exec(); // <- exec() devuelve una Promesa
  console.log(resultado);

// muestra lo siguiente si hay algún resultado:
// [
//   {
//    "_id": ObjectId("5f9041196462be3c5ca1e53d"),
//     "detalleInsumos": [
//       {
//         "_id": ObjectId("5f9041196462be3c5ca1e540"),
//         "codigoInsumo": "20000001",
//         // ... otros campos
//       }
//     ]
//   }
// ]
}
catch(e) {
  // manejo de errores
}
```

Comment: Excelente explicación!!, agradezco tu tiempo y tu ayuda, muchas gracias.

Answer (score 0):

Bueno la documentación de Mongoose(creo que lo estás usando) marca lo siguiente con respecto al método findOne:

```
// Find one adventure whose `country` is 'Croatia', otherwise `null`
await Adventure.findOne({ country: 'Croatia' }).exec();

// using callback
Adventure.findOne({ country: 'Croatia' }, function (err, adventure) {});

// select only the adventures name and length
await Adventure.findOne({ country: 'Croatia' }, 'name length').exec();
```

Tu ejemplo se parece al primer caso, intenta colocarle el exec al final del query.

Comment: Sigue dando el mismo resultado a la hora de hacer la consulta. Perdón por no especificarlo al inicio, sí estoy usando Mongoose.